# How to send a notification to the OneSignal API with flurl

Tags: .net-core, onesignal, flurl

I'm trying to send some data using the example in the page of onesignal

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications") as HttpWebRequest;

request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

request.Headers.Add("authorization", "Basic xxx");

var obj = new
{
    app_id = "xxx",
    contents = new { en = "English Message" },
    included_segments = new string[] { "Active Users" }
};
var param = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(param);
```

This coded works fine, but I'm using Flurl to make a request to onesignal like this:

```
var body = new
{
    app_id = "xxx",
    contents = new
    {
        es = "Mensaje prueba"

    },
    included_segments = new string[] { "All" }
};
string param = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
var content = new System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(param));

var response = await new Flurl.Url(urlbase)
    .AppendPathSegment("notifications")
    .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    .WithHeader("Authorization", "Basic xxx")
    .PostAsync(content)
    .ReceiveString();
```

but I'm getting the "Bad request". Please someone could help to point how to make the same call with Flurl?

Comment: Just use `PostJsonAsync(body)` instead of `PostAsync`, do not serialize a body itself. Let Flurl do it its way.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the first comment, you're doing more work than you need to. Flurl will serialize `body` for you, so remove these lines:

```
string param = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
var content = new System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(param));
```

And post `body` directly using `PostJsonAsync`:

```
var response = await urlbase
    ...
    .PostJsonAsync(body)
    .ReceiveString();
```